# Grails Filter viewModel data is null?

Tags: grails, view, filter, nullpointerexception

So I am creating an App where I want to pass data to a layout for the purpose of building content up. So as I am passing the data to a Layout I created a filter in order to do so and this filter basically just looks at the current user logged in and then goes into there account and finally looks at all the options on their account, as shown below:

```
class OptionsFilters {

    def springSecurityService

    def filters = {
        all(controller:'*', action:'*') {
            before = {

            }
            after = { viewModel ->

                if(springSecurityService.currentUser != null && springSecurityService.currentUser.acc.options.size() > 0)
                {

                    viewModel.options = springSecurityService.currentUser.acc.options
                }

            }
            afterView = { Exception e ->

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now this is done I have the following code that is designed to hide that data unless the user has the option to see it:

```
<g:each var="option" in="${ options }">

    <g:if test="${option.name == 'email'}">

        //The data to show if they have the option

    </g:if>

</g:each>
```

Now the funny thing is this code works fine if the users Account already has options attached (or at least 1), however the scenario is that I run the app and I have a user who has an account with no options on it, so for the time being the data in the layout is hidden. Then when I go into their account and add say an "email" option and hit save I expect the correct Show view to be displayed and now the content in the Layout should also be visible. However this is not what happens and I get this error:

```
Cannot set property 'options' on null object. Stacktrace follows:
Message: Cannot set property 'options' on null object
   Line | Method
->>  25 | doCall   in tool.OptionsFilters$_closure1_closure2_closure4
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   195 | doFilter in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|    63 | doFilter in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|   895 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   918 | run . .  in     ''
^   662 | run      in java.lang.Thread
```

From my testing I have noticed that this error only seems to happening when I am updating the options for my own account. I presume its some sort of timing issue between me updating the account options attached to my username and the filter looking at that data for processing.

I would appreciate any assistance on this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Once you "save" a new option, do you redirect to the action which shows the page or just render a model? My point here is that `after` filter will intercept post-save but your intention is to have it intercepted while displaying the page.

Comment: Also make it null safe `.?` like `viewModel?.options = "hello"` seems not always the viewModel exist.

Comment: in the Options Controller in the "update" action I am doing a redirect at the end like so: redirect(action: "show", id: optionsInstance.id)

Comment: Hi Alidad thanks I have made the viewModel null safe and is all ok now thanks for the help on this :)